# Delete Repeating Calendar Events in iOS 7.0.4

Tags: iphone, calendar

I have an iPhone 4 and use the calendar feature often.  Deleting events used to be simple, but at the moment I've found that I cannot delete an existing repeating event.

I can tap on the event and view the details.  There used to be an "Edit" button for repeating events, where you could select to delete either one instance of the event, or all instances of the event.  That "Edit" button is no longer there though, and I cannot find any other way to delete the series.

Software version is iOS 7.0.4.  Does anyone know how I can get rid of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed to read/write in that calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Tapping on an event should give you an edit button in the upper right. From there you scroll down to the very bottom and will see the option to delete the event(s).

`delete event >`  [image: ios events]

Comment: That doesn't work.  There is no 'edit' button for me to tap on.  I can view the event details, but there is no 'edit' button anywhere.